# Grails ajax radio buttons

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm looking to have two radio groups within a single form. When you select a radio button (product type) form the first group, I'd like to update the second group (quantity) and adjust the price using Ajax. Does Grails offer an Ajax radio solution?

```
<form>
   <div>
      Product Type
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1"/>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2"/>
      <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3"/>
   </div>

   <div>
      Quantity
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1"/> ${price}
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2"/> ${price}
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3"/> ${price}
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4"/> ${price}
      <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5"/> ${price}
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the g:formRemote tag:

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/formRemote.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @user4978426 I don't think this answers my question. It looks as if formremote would require a form submission inorder to work. I'm looking to update the values of the second radio field before ever submitting the form.